# How can I get XML data in Python/Django passed in POST request?

Tags: python, xml, django, post

There is XML data passed in POST request as a simple string and not inside some name=value pair,
with HTTP header (optionally) set to `'Content-Type: text/xml'`.

How can I get this data in Python (by its own ways or by tools of Django)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you just want to know how to access the POST data? You can get that via `request.body`, which will contain your XML as a string. You can then use your favourite Python XML parser on it.

Comment: Yes, accessing POST data is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It works as expected, thank you :) Does it work in Django only?

Comment: I don't know where else you would use it. The HttpRequest class is defined in Django, yes.

Comment: There is `request.body` also in Flask. Perhaps, some kind of a standard.